# pandas transform data into multi step time series based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

i have a dataframe like below and i'm creating a multistep sequence of data using below for loop but i want to apply the logic at a customer level.

Dataframe :

```
Date    Customer    Price
1/1/2019    A   142
1/2/2019    A   123
1/3/2019    A   342
1/4/2019    A   232
1/5/2019    A   657
1/6/2019    B   875    
1/7/2019    B   999    
1/8/2019    B   434    
1/9/2019    B   564    
1/10/2019   B   345    
1/10/2019   B   798
```

Below forloop code can create sequence of data having a rolling window 1.

```
data = np.array(data)
X_data, y_data = [], []
for i in range(2, len(data )-2):
    X_data.append(data[i-2:i])
    y_data.append(data[i:i+2])
```

The output of X_data array and y_data array should look like below

```
X_data(independent variables)   y_data(target)
customer  0   1                   0    1
   A      142 123                342   232
   A      123 342                232   657
   B      875 999                434   564
   B      999 434                564   345
   B      434 564                345   798
```

Please suggest me on this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas-dataframe-shift) to shift index by desired number for rolling data

```py
def get_rolling_data(row):
    n = 2
    for i in range(n):
        row[f'x_data.{i}'] = row.shift(0 - i).Price
        row[f'y_data.{i}'] = row.shift(0 - n - i).Price
    return row

df_res = df.groupby(['Customer']).apply(get_rolling_data)
print(df_res.dropna())

       Date Customer  Price  x_data.0  x_data.1  y_data.0  y_data.1
0  1/1/2019        A    142       142     123.0     342.0     232.0
1  1/2/2019        A    123       123     342.0     232.0     657.0
5  1/6/2019        B    875       875     999.0     434.0     564.0
6  1/7/2019        B    999       999     434.0     564.0     345.0
7  1/8/2019        B    434       434     564.0     345.0     798.0
```

Above result is a `Dataframe`. You can further extract the required data if you need `np.array` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the solution henry ,but if i have 60 and more price rows per customer and instead of generating 2 columns i want to generate 30 columns per customer with rolling window 1 like for x :x_data1,x_data2...x_data30 similarly for y:y_data1, y_data2......y_data30,will the above code work ?

Comment: i don't see why it works for case=2 but not for case=30, for readability you can generalize those `x_data1`, `x_data2`... `x_data30` into a for loop

Comment: I tried to put in the for loop but getting some error,can u pls help me to generalize the above code in to a for loop,thanks in advance

Comment: edited the answer to use a for loop within `get_rolling_data()`

Comment: I’m getting  syntax error  for row[f’x_data.{i}’] ..can u please help me on this and i’m using python2.7

Comment: try to replace it with `row[’x_data.{}’.format(i)]`

Comment: Got it thanks and can u pls tell me if i want to get x_data with 5 columns and y_data with 2 columns with rolling window of 1,can u pls help me on this,thanks in advance